# How to make active links stay active?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I'm trying to have my links stay the hover state when they're on the page (so when they're on the page the link will be blue/underlined) I've checked out a few other pages but they were confusing to me, here is part of my code:

```
a:link{
   font-family: avenir;
   letter-spacing: .3px;
   text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
   color: #2ab9d8; 
   font-size: 12px; 
   letter-spacing: .3px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-decoration: none;
   -webkit-transition: all ease-in 133ms;
   -moz-transition: all ease-in 133ms;
   -o-transition: all ease-in 133ms;
   -ms-transition: all ease-in 133ms;
    transition: all ease-in 133ms;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #2ab9d8;
}
```

Comment: your question is unclear to me :-(

Comment: so lets say I have a link that says work and when you hover over it, it turns blue. I want the link to stay blue when you go to the page

Comment: you should keep track of the links that receive a hover event. you can do this with cookies or browser storage.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand your question correct but I think just give the specific element you want a class (most of the ppl make it active) and make its style with the CSS

```
<a href="#" class="active">what ever</a>


.active{
color: #2ab9d8; 
font-size: 12px; 
letter-spacing: .3px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: all ease-in 133ms;
-moz-transition: all ease-in 133ms;
-o-transition: all ease-in 133ms;
-ms-transition: all ease-in 133ms;
 transition: all ease-in 133ms;
border-bottom: 1px solid #2ab9d8;

}
```

Comment: I would expand on this by saying you should simply add the `.active` selector to your original style definition. `a:hover, a.active {`

Answer (score 0):

You want links to stay underlined and blue?

```
a:link{
  font-family: avenir;
  letter-spacing: .3px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

**text-decoration: underline; color: blue;** do the magic.

Take a look here for an example and modify the code on the run
http://jsfiddle.net/maurospinello/h48s2qtm/